# How to get options from an object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I am trying to get options with a specific data value out of a variable which I saved all the available options inside.

```
var optionSaver = $('#directory option');
console.log(optionSaver);

$('#projectOrOrganizations').change(function () {
    var id = $('#projectOrOrganizations').find(':selected').data('contextid');
    console.log(id);

    var options = $('option[data-parentid='+id+']', optionSaver);

    console.log(options);

    $('#directory').html(options);
});
```

the optionSaver should persist as long as the the change listener is active

EDIT:

The Html as requsted:

```
<select name="project" id="projectOrOrganizations">
    <option name="organisationOrProjectName_78" data-contextid="78">Organisationsvorlage</option>
    <option name="organisationOrProjectName_80" data-contextid="80"> Projektvorlage</option>
</select>

<select name="directory" id="directory">
    <option  data-parentid="78" value="Verzeichnis">Verzeichnis</option>
    <option  data-parentid="80" value="Verzeichnis">Verzeichnis2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: And where is your HTML of `#directory`?

Comment: So what's the problem..?

Comment: I cant get the options (optionSaver) which are located in #directory to save permanently. They get overwritten each time the function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use filter() here because the `option` element what you are looking for is not descendant of the `optionSaver`, but it is a member of `optionSaver`. So

```
var options = optionSaver.filter('option[data-parentid='+id+']');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the variable data you should be using a variable with a greater scope. You define id and options in the scope of the change event. Therefore you should create a variable out of the change event and save it there.